# Redirect google bots only

Tags: linux, apache

Is there a way we can redirect Google Bots only and not humans?

I have a page that ranks quite well but would like to leave it available if typed in directly in URL but not via Search Engine listing

Is this possible with .htaccess or robots.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not rely on just `robots.txt`. Not all crawlers respect this.

You can look for certain tell-tale signs that your web server is being accessed by a bot, and give it an HTTP response of your choice.

Example: I was being bothered by frequent accesses by Yandex Bot:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yandex [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://go.away [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt will do the job for you, but it might take a few days (weeks).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are seeking for : http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Comment: Please be advised that I do not want to exclude the page at all!!! I just want to redirect the bots to another external domain